# Filter repeated (by integer) items in a List<Tuple<int,Image>> and create a Dictionary<int, List<Image>> C#

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary

I have a list of tuples, each tuple has an integer and an image, the list has several items with the same integer value, but distinct image, so I want to get items in list with the same integer and then create a list of images from their corresponding item on list.

For instance suppose I have **3 images**

**imageL1_1** and **imageL1_2** are on list with same integer **1**

**imageL2_1** is on list with value **2**

```
Image imageL1_1 = new Image();
imageL1_1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/image1.png", UriKind.Relative));
Image imageL1_2 = new Image();
imageL1_2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/image2.png", UriKind.Relative));
Image imageL2_1 = new Image();
imageL2_1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/image3.png", UriKind.Relative));
List<Tuple<int,Image>> source = new List<Tuple<int,Image>>();
source.Add(new Tuple<int,Image>(1,imageL1_1 ));
source.Add(new Tuple<int,Image>(1,imageL1_2));
source.Add(new Tuple<int,Image>(2,imageL2_1 ));
```

I want to filter these items and create a dictionary that looks like:

```
List<Image> l1 = new List<Image>();
 l1.Add(imageL1_1);
 l1.Add(imageL1_2);

List<Image> l2 = new List<Image>();
l2.Add(imageL2_1);

Dictionary<int, List<Image>> dictImages = new Dictionary<int, List<Image>>()
{
     {1, l1},
     {2, l2}
};
```

I was trying:

```
Dictionary<int, List<Image>> result = new Dictionary<int, List<Image>>();
List<Image> listIm = new List<Image>();
foreach (Tuple<int, Image> diff in temp)
{

   //How should I save items until key is different?? 
   if(someCondition)
   {
      listIm.Add(diff.Item2);     //save item on temp list
   } 
   else
   {
      result.Add(diff.Item1, listIm); //save result on Dictionary 
      listIm.Clear();                 //clean list 
    }
}
```

I am having hard time to figure out the condition to either save item on list or save element on dictionary, How to solve it?

Could this be done using `LINQ`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
Dictionary<int, List<Image>> result = 
    source.GroupBy(tuple => tuple.Item1, tuple => tuple.Item2)
        .ToDictionary(grouping => grouping.Key, grouping => new List<Image>(grouping));
```

Basically, this groups your list of items in `source` by the given key (`tuple.Item1`) and then converts the grouping into a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Interesting solution, so grouping contains all images that has same key that were grouped, is it correct?